# EntityType 'Attribute' has no key defined even though [key] is defined

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, primary-key

I am using Entity Framework 5 to access data from SQL Server 2008 R2 in an MVC 4 Application. This is my T_Attribute class:

```
    public partial class T_Attribute
{
    public T_Attribute()
    {
        this.T_Characteristic = new HashSet<T_Characteristic>();
        this.T_Category = new HashSet<T_Category>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    public string Descr { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> HasCharacteristics { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<T_Characteristic> T_Characteristic { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<T_Category> T_Category { get; set; }
}
```

My exact Error is "EntityType 'Attribute' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.". In my other entity-classes this was resolved by adding the [Key]-parameter

The variables have exactly the same names as in the database.

Thanks in adavance for your help.

Stack Trace:

> [ModelValidationException: One or more validation errors were detected
>   during model generation:
>
> \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'Attribute' has
>   no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: Name: The specified name is
>   not allowed: '__DynamicallyInvokableAttribute'.
>   \tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet
>   'T_Attribute1' is based on type 'Attribute' that has no keys defined.
>   ]
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateAndSerializeCsdl(EdmModel
>   model, XmlWriter writer) +114
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Edm.EdmModelExtensions.ValidateCsdl(EdmModel
>   model) +77
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +218
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +107
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +143
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +171
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +498    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +31    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +39
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +137
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +38    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +84    System.Linq.Queryable.Select(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 selector) +66
>   HP.GPS.ClearingCenter.Application.Products.CategoryDataService.GetAllCategories()
>   in *FilepathToSolution*.Application\Products\CategoryDataService.cs:22
>   HP.GPS.ClearingCenter.Web.ViewModels.Home.IndexViewModel.Initialize()
>   in *FilepathToSolution*.Web\ViewModels\Home\IndexViewModel.cs:27
>   *Solution*.Web.Controllers.HomeController.Search() in *FilepathToSolution*.Web\Controllers\HomeController.cs:22    lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +101
>   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase
>   controller, Object[] parameters) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +434
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +60
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeSynchronousActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +50
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   +75    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   _) +44    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +139    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +102
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +49
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
>   +126    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +323    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +139    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +102
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +50
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.b__20()
>   +68    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +184    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
>   +136    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Object tag) +56
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +40
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +39
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +45
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +47    System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +151
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +59
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.End(IAsyncResult asyncResult,
>   Object tag) +40
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +40    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +38
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651188    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Comment: Try giving it a name like AttId

Comment: That didn't help me either. Even calling it T_AttributeId (so tablename + Id as somewhere mentionend) didn't help. Thanks though

Comment: Can you please post the references of the cs file

Comment: Try adding the [Required] attribute below key attribute

Comment: Required didn't fix it either
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the Database and going over to Code-First solved the problem for me. Thanks for your help.